# Question on Indefinite Integrals (Calculus II)

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

hope you are doing well. I am working on a problem solving the following indefinite integral :

$$\int 6x \sqrt{2x^3+8}\, dx$$

I have gotten up to the point where :

$$\int \sqrt{u}\frac{du}{x}$$

But am stuck as I am not sure where to place the $x$, not sure if I have done an incorrect method or am missing something. Thank you for your assistance in advance :)

Comment: What substitution did you use? It looks like you did not finish everywhere with it. You should never have both $x$ and $u$ in the integral.

Comment: Initially I let x - 2x^3 +8 then let du = 6x^2 and dx = du/6x^2. Then the 6x was cancelled by the 6x^2 under du (6x * du/6x^2) and that's how I got there. You seem to be stating the problem is having two unknowns @Andrei ?

Comment: I am ready to bet that the problem is  $$\int 6x^2 \sqrt{2x^3+8}\, dx\qquad \text{or} \qquad  \int 6x \sqrt{2x^2+8}\, dx$$

Comment: Ahh this makes a lot more sense, I'll check again with the source of the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is fine. Let $u=2x^3+8$, $\frac{du}{dx}=6x^2$.

Hence $$\int 6x\sqrt{2x^3+8}\, dx = \int \frac{\sqrt{u}}{x}\, du$$

However, I do not expect this integral to have a nice form. Wolfram alpha expressed the solution in hypergeometric function.[image]

Comment: I see, so from what you are stating there isn't another way to solve beyond what I have done without incorporating the "hypergeometric function" ?

Comment: There must by a typo (have a look at my comment). There are two possibilities. Cheers :-)